# Adobe Dynamic Tag Manager - tool Customize Page Code

Tags: dynamic, tags, adobe, adobe-analytics

I need one clarification about the "Customize Page Code" tool settings of the Adobe DTM.
As the official guide reports, this code can be executed **Before or After UI settings** with the details below:
-  Before UI settings: Interface settings take precedence over the custom code (for example,
if you want to override an eVar if a setting in the interface was enabled).
-  After UI settings: Custom code takes precedence over interface settings.
My doubt concerns what the "interface" is, because I set a code to be executed "After UI settings" but it is triggered before the first s.t() call anyway.
The guide is not clear when i writes: *"if a setting in the interface was enabled"*.
What this "setting in the interface" is intended to be?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gives you a choice of whether to have the code block executed before or after the other settings in the tool config.  "Settings in the interface" is anything within the main tool config page.

The `s.t()` call is not part of the tool config page. The `s.t()` call gets executed after everything in the tool config, regardless of which way you want to order the stuff within the tool config.

The `s.t()` call may also be executed either before or after page load rules, depending on whether you set the main tool config to load the library on "page top" or "page bottom", vs. when/where you set the page load rule to trigger at.

Comment: Thank you Crayon, you've been very clear and helpful